# JavaScript: how to update progress bar inside nested for loops?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, requestanimationframe

I have some nested for loops that take a while to run, so I want to display a progress bar. The problem is that this is not an inherently async process, it is a block of code with 3 nested loops.  I tried a slew of ways to yield so as to render the page, with and without `requestAnimationFrame()`, async await, and an async generator w/for await...of.  The snippet below represents the only way I could get it to work.

Is there a better way to do this? One that doesn't involve calling the generator function inside the animation callback, for example.

```js
let i, start, val;
const progress = document.getElementsByTagName("progress")[0];
function run() {
  i = 0;
  val = 0;
  start = performance.now();
  requestAnimationFrame(animateProgress);
}
function animateProgress() {
  const next = loop().next();
  if (!next.done) {
    progress.value = next.value;
    frame = requestAnimationFrame(animateProgress);
  }
  else
    console.log(`Calculations took ${performance.now() - start}ms`);
}
function* loop() {
  let j;
  while (i < 100) {
    for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      ++val;
    }
    ++i;
    yield val;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:1rem;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">Run</button>
<progress value="0" max="10000"></progress>
```

Comment: you need to run each loop iteration asynchronously, e.g. with `setInterval()`. A synchronous loop blocks the UI, so the progress won't render.

Comment: "*a better way that doesn't involve calling the generator function inside the animation callback*" - but that's exactly how one would use generators. If you don't want to have to run it yourself, use `async`/`await` where you write `await animationFrame();` instead of `yield;`.

Comment: @Bergi First time I ever used a generator, so at least I used it properly :)  Though I had to edit my snippet because the `i` variable must be set outside of the generator function or the animation loop never exits because `i` gets reset to zero every time the generator function is called.  In that sense I could just put the inner for loop inside the animation callback and not use a generator. I can't `await requestAnimationFrame()` because it's not an async function and it returns immediately.  How would I `await` the next frame inside the for loop?

Comment: I meant create a helper function `animationFrame` that calls `requestAnimationFrame` and returns a promise for it. Pretty much what Alexander did in his answer below

Comment: @Bergi that sounds like Alexander's 2nd snippet which throttles the while loop with the animation callback (it takes ~16,653ms = 999 * 16.67ms to iterate 1000 times).  I had tried and rejected that approach prior to posting this question. His first snippet avoids `requestAnimationFrame()` altogether.  I ended up doing a variation on that first snippet that incorporates `requestAnimationFrame()`, as you can see by my unaccepted answer below.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your calculations in a worker if they aren't DOM manipulations:

```js
const progress = document.getElementsByTagName("progress")[0];

const executeFunctionInWorker = function(fn, progressCb){

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const blob = new Blob([`
    let start = performance.now();
    (${fn.toString()})();
    postMessage({duration: performance.now() - start});
    `], {type: 'application/javascript'});
    const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    worker.addEventListener('message', e => {
      if('duration' in e.data){
        resolve(e.data.duration);
      }else{
        progressCb(e.data.progress);
      }
    });
  });
  
};

const doComputation = () => {
  let count = 0;
  while(count++<1000){
    structuredClone(Array.from({length: 30000}, () => Math.random()));      
    postMessage({progress: Math.round(count/1000 * 100)});
  }
};

const run = async() => {
  $run.disabled = true;
  const duration = await executeFunctionInWorker(doComputation, value => progress.value = value);
  $run.disabled = false;
  console.log('Calculations took', duration, 'ms');
};
```

```css
* {
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:1rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="$run" onclick="run()">Run</button>
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

On the main thread (note how much it's slower, since we need to calculate and report the progress):

```js
const progress = document.getElementsByTagName("progress")[0];

const doComputation = async () => {
  let count = 0;
  while(count++<1000){
    structuredClone(Array.from({length: 30000}, () => Math.random()));      
    await new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(() => (progress.value = Math.round(count/1000 * 100), resolve())));
  }
};

const run = async() => {
  $run.disabled = true;
  const start = performance.now();
  await doComputation();
  $run.disabled = false;
  console.log('Calculations took', performance.now() - start, 'ms');
};
```

```css
* {
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:1rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="$run" onclick="run()">Run</button>
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: I was looking for a reason to learn about and use Workers, so this is apt.  That said, I have never used Workers and I will have to fiddle around to understand and adapt your answer to my code.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't have time until to day to dig into this new topic of Worker until today.  Your answer helped a lot and I upvoted and accepted it.  Note: the reason your second snippet is slow is that you're throttling the while loop with the `requestAnimationFrame()` callbacks. On Firefox @60hz it takes ~16,653ms to run: that's 999 * 16.67 (1,000x loop). Also note my unaccepted answer below, which is the way I ended up implementing it.  The progress bar animation is smoother, but it's a tiny bit slower, not sure why that would be.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer pointed me towards workers, which is the best solution IMO. But I went with a variation on that answer, so I'm posting it as an alternate implementation. This method produces a smoother progress animation, as you might expect by the use of `requestAnimationFrame()` (*it's easier to see the difference in Chrome vs Firefox because Firefox is twice as fast*). It is also organized in the way I had originally envisioned but had been unable to implement. The performance seems comparable, maybe a little bit slower than the accepted answer.

The idea is to make the counter independent from the animation loop and to update the progress element from the animation callback. Here it is as adapted from the accepted answer:

```js
let count, frame;
const progress = document.getElementsByTagName("progress")[0];
function raf() {
  progress.value = count;
  requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}
function executeFunctionInWorker(fn) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const blob = new Blob([`
      let start = performance.now();
      (${fn.toString()})();
      postMessage({duration: performance.now() - start});
      `], {type: 'application/javascript'}
    );
    const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    worker.addEventListener('message', e => {
      if('duration' in e.data){
        resolve(e.data.duration);
      }else{
        count = e.data.progress;
      }
    });
  });
}
function doComputation() {
  let c = 0;
  while(c++ < 1000){
    structuredClone(Array.from({length: 30000}, () => Math.random()));
    postMessage({progress: c});
  }
}
async function run() {
  $run.disabled = true;
  count = 0;
  frame = requestAnimationFrame(raf);
  const duration = await executeFunctionInWorker(doComputation);
  cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
  $run.disabled = false;
  console.log('Calculations took', duration, 'ms', count);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="$run" onclick="run()">Run</button>
<progress value="0" max="1000"></progress>
```